# Agrupación por interacción Over-Partition

Tags: sql-server, agrupación

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto el cual consiste en agrupara las interacciones de una forma determinada con el siguiente código de muestra:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Data')       IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Data      END

SET DATEFIRST 1;

CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [empleado_id]   VARCHAR(5),
    [date]          DATE,
    [time_start]    TIME(0),
    [time_end]      TIME(0),
    [excepcion]     VARCHAR(15),
    [excep_start]   TIME(0),
    [excep_end]     TIME(0)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','break'   ,'13:00:00','13:15:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','lunch'   ,'15:00:00','16:00:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','op'      ,'17:30:00','18:00:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','break'   ,'13:15:00','13:30:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','feedback','18:00:00','18:15:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','op'      ,'17:15:00','17:30:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','feedback','18:45:00','19:00:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','break'   ,'18:30:00','18:45:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','op'      ,'17:00:00','17:15:00'),
       ('1022','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','op'      ,'17:00:00','17:15:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-15','10:00:00','19:00:00','op'      ,'17:00:00','17:15:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-14','10:00:00','19:00:00','feedback','18:15:00','18:30:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-18','07:00:00','19:30:00','uno','13:15:00','13:30:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-18','07:00:00','19:30:00','uno','13:30:00','13:45:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-18','07:00:00','19:30:00','dos','14:00:00','14:15:00'),
       ('1011','2020-07-18','07:00:00','19:30:00','dos','15:00:00','15:15:00');


;WITH cte_uno AS (
                SELECT [empleado_id]
                        ,[date]
                        ,[time_start]
                        ,[time_end]
                        ,[excepcion]
                        ,[excep_start]
                        ,[excep_end]
                        ,[ord_dia]  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [empleado_id] ORDER BY [empleado_id],[date])
                FROM #Data
                ) 
SELECT * FROM cte_uno
```

La idea es tener esta data (previamente ordenada):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esta otra, una agrupación de interacciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto con el fin de agrupar una sola interacción con un intervalo de menor a mayor, es decir, que en base a la columna de `[excepcion]` me de el valor mas bajo y el mas alto en el tiempo de esa excepción pero siempre considerando si hay otra excepción en medio. Como se muestra en las capturas anteriores.

La única restricción "mayor" es tener el resultado como se muestra en la segunda captura (misma cantidad de columnas y funcionabilidad)

Cabe mencionar que e intentado hacer por CTEs pero termine realizando algo muy poco funcional y poco ortodoxo.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea estaría agradecido. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás ante un problema que en inglés conozco como "huecos e islas" (gaps and islands). Una de las formas más sencillas que conozco para solucionarlo es mediante el uso de dos `ROW_NUMBER` con distintas particiones.

```
WITH cte_uno AS (
                SELECT [empleado_id]
                        ,[date]
                        ,[time_start]
                        ,[time_end]
                        ,[excepcion]
                        ,[excep_start]
                        ,[excep_end]
                        ,[grupo_excep]  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [empleado_id] ORDER BY [empleado_id],[date], [excep_start])
                                        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [empleado_id], excepcion ORDER BY [empleado_id],[date], [excep_start])
                FROM #Data
                ) 
SELECT empleado_id,
    date,
    time_start,
    time_end,
    excepcion,
    MIN(excep_start) AS excep_start,
    MAX(excep_end  ) AS excep_end  
FROM cte_uno
GROUP BY  empleado_id,
    date,
    time_start,
    time_end,
    excepcion,
    [grupo_excep]
ORDER BY date, empleado_id, excep_start;
```

Si te interesa aprender más, te sugiero que busques el termino en inglés y encontrarás grandes recursos que podrían ser traducidos en caso de que no domines el idioma.

Comment: Como siempre Luis, mil gracias por tu aportación. Sabes... solo encontré un detalle en tu solución, donde tengo dos excepciones iguales seguidas pero en distintos intervalos y estas se terminaron sumando... Sigo probando con alguna forma de discriminar esa parte pero ahi le llevo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo del problema en tus datos de prueba para poder trabajar sobre eso?

Comment: Añadí los ejemplos del día 18, si puedes, solo toma esos días para pruebas ya que representa, la unificación de un intervalo completo (por excepción "uno") y la separación de otra en distintos intervalos (la excepción "dos"). Gracias de antemano.